# Error con Mercurial y Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, mercurial

Tengo este error en *Mercurial* y *Jenkins*:

> Salida de consola:
>
> Started by user `admin`
>   Building in `workspace /jenkins/jobs/proyecto/workspace`
>   `[WS-CLEANUP]` Delete project workspace...
>   `[WS-CLEANUP]` Done
>   `$hg clone --rev default --noupdate` http://admin:admin1234@rhodecode.com/admin/proyecto3 **/jenkins/jobs/proyecto/workspace**
>   Abort: HTTP Error 404: **Not found**
>   Error: Failed to clone http://admin:admin1234@rhodecode.com/admin/proyecto3
>   Error: Failed to clone http://admin:admin1234@rhodecode.com/admin/proyecto3
>   Finished: Failure

Comment: Por favor Diego, revisa tu pregunta, tiene serios problemas de formato. Trata de explicar que error tienes, y si es posible agrega un __[mcve]__.

Answer (score 1):

No utilice los datos de autorización en URL, obtenga una URL normal (despojada)

```
hg clone ... http://rhodecode.com/admin/proyecto3
```

y `[auth]` Sección en Mercurial ini-archivo global

```
[auth]
rhodecode.com.prefix = rhodecode.com
rhodecode.com.username = admin
rhodecode.com.password = admin1234
```